# Issue On Displaying Pages with Post Name Permalink

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

I have a simple Theme like below

[image]

Right now when I navigate to localhost and site root directory I am able to see content from `header.php , footer.php and page.php`.

then, I simply generated some pages for Navigation bar and to get a better URL I updated the permalink from default to Post Name format

[image]

Now while I have the the clean Ur as: `Permalink: http://localhost/RumiPress/eyeglasses/`

[image]

But when I click to view the page I am getting

[image]

I Google this and find some hints about the (.htaccess) so I just copied same format as Cedex 
[image]

but still getting same result. Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Hi mevius, actually not! can you please let me know what is it?

Comment: LEFT click on the green WAMP icon in your notification tray --> Apache --> Apache modules --> rewrite_module (make sure it's checked)

Comment: Great thanks, just one quick question how about reall server side? I mean right now I am using award-space free hosting. how can I do this there?

Comment: mod_rewrite is usually enabled by default by most hosting companies. If not, if award-space allows you to edit your Apache mods-available/mods-enabled, you can enable it yourself. Otherwise, contact your hosting provider and have them enable it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)  module needs to be enabled in order for "pretty" permalinks to work in WordPress, as [specified in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite).

You're using WAMP, so this can be done by:

1. LEFT click on the green WAMP icon in your notification tray
2. Click on Apache --> Apache modules
3. Enable rewrite_module (make sure it's checked)